# preg_replace isn't working as expected

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I wrote a simple function which takes a block of text, extracts urls from it, and replaces all urls with an `<a href>` tag around them.

E.g `http://site.com` should become `<a href="http://site.com">http://site.com</a>`

Code:

```
function parseUrls( $string )
{
    $string = trim($string);
    $pattern = '%\bhttp[s]?://[A-z0-9/\.\-_]+%i';
    $replacement = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';

    $string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

    return $string;
}
```

However if I pass the following string as input:

hello https://google.com test http://test.com/something.html abc http://site.com

The output I get is:

```
hello <a href=""></a> test <a href=""></a> abc <a href=""></a>
```

I.e so the urls are being matched, but `$replacement` isn't being applied correctly. May be my usage of `$1` is wrong somehow?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't set any capturing groups. Try adding (...) around your url match.

Comment: I had to +1 the question because of your name. I always follow instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a capturing group that `$1` would refer to.

Use `$replacement = '<a href="$0" target="_BLANK">$0</a>';` instead.

Also, don't use `A-z` in your character class (it matches more than you think: there are some non-letter characters between ASCII `Z` and `a`). `A-Z` is enough since you've made it case-insensitive anyway.

Comment: Thanks for thhe catch on `A-z`

Answer (score 6):

**There is no capture group defined in your expression** (usually done by `()`). So `$1` is empty. However `$0` holds the full match string in your replace pattern.

So either use,

```
$replacement = '<a href="$0" target="_BLANK">$0</a>';
```

or

```
$pattern = '%\b(http[s]?://[A-z0-9/\.\-_]+)%i';
//             ^                          ^
//             |                          |
//             +-----  Capture group -----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group the expression with the brackets in order to use $1.

> $pattern = '%\b(http[s]?://[A-z0-9/.-_]+)%i';